# HIBERNATE: Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to use hibernate reverse engineering to auto generate my entity model from my mysql database. I am using mysql server 8 and developing a spring boot app 2.2.4.. In my application I already included spring-jpa and mysql connection driver in my build.gradle.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 jcenter()
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
 implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19'
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I downgraded my java library and java compiler to 1.8, but originally I am using java 11. The reason I downgraded to java 1.8 is that the hibernate configuration is not detecting my project's classpath.

my mysql java connector: mysql-connector-java-8.0.19

[hibernate config part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6N8y.png)

[hibernate config part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OLQ8.png)

[ERROR message from hibernate configuration when viewing the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dpBM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded my mysql version to 5.x and it is now working. I have no idea why it is not working with my version 8